# Color Palette Algorithm with Canvas - HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Hello I want to generate some random colors based on a six-color-palette that I already have.

The idea is create a list and each element has a different color, if the list has more than 6 elements, the 7th color will be based on the 1st of the list, the 8th will be based on the 2nd and so on, but the new color will be a little different, may be it will be lighter or darker.

My palette is this:

- Color 1 (Green) :
  Hex: #acff68
  RGB: (172, 255, 194)
- Color 2 (Blue) :
  Hex: #8db9f5
  RGB: (141, 185, 245)
- Color 3 (Red) :
  Hex: #e45050
  RGB: (228, 80, 80)
- Color 4 (Yellow) :
  Hex: #f5f069
  RGB: (245, 240, 105)
- Color 5 (Brown) :
  Hex: #cec192
  RGB: (206, 193, 146)
- Color 6 (Pink) :
  Hex: #f59494
  RGB: (245, 148, 148)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch between RGB and HSV (Hue, Saturation, Brightness). 
After you get HSV from RGB, you can adjust its brightness and convert it into RGB value again. 
 
check this wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Comment: @victorhqc and don't forget to check this answer if it does help you :)

Comment: It did! thanks ;) but I can't check the answer, not enough reputation :( I'm still working in the generated colors though. I used HSL model instead of HSV.
I found this rgb - hsl - hsv javascript functions that also helped
http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript

Comment: @victorhqc you can use either HSL or HSV model :) and about the checking thing, checking answer doesn't need any privilege while voting up does. you can check this answer by clicking empty check image on the left side of vote up/down buttons.

Comment: lol thanks, and yup- HSL and HSV saved my life. Thanks a lot :)